# mounting NAS share to be accesible from apps?

Tags: mount

I have no problem accessing and using my NAS data/files in "Files", but when I try to use them with apps I can't see them?
How can I mount/map network drive (preferably auto-mount at boot), so that it is visible and usable, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorted...
by adding following line to fstab:

```
//192.168.1.101/My_data     /media/synologymount    cifs    credentials=/home/username/pswd,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0      0      0
```

following advice here:
https://youtu.be/v2WMnZoiGog

Having said so - is there perhaps an easier way of doing it in elementary OS?

Comment: I got caught by it, trying to set up another NAS share 10 month later, so here is a WARNING for anybody trying to follow my advice above - it (setting up fstab) will NOT work unless you also install cifs utilities <sudo apt install cifs-utils>